# Is it possible to disable reflection from a .NET assembly?

Tags: .net, reflection

I would like to run a third party .NET assembly on my API. I want to let it call its own methods and objects as it wishes, but deny it access to anything that my API doesn't explicitly give it. In particular, if my API passes an object to the third party code as `IMyObject` I don't want them using reflection or any method to elevate that object to, say `MyObject` that implements the interface.

Is there a way to deny the ability to use reflection in this third party assembly? I have full control of everything, so I don't need to stop people from decompiling my assembly, just abusing it at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is running an assembly in a sandbox. This can be achieved uisng `CAS (Code Access Security)` in .Net.

Here is how it works. You create an `AppDomain`, assign limited permissions to it. For example, you allow displaying a UI but don't allow using File System or Reflection. Then you load an assembly into it and let it run.

.Net 4.0 introduces a whole new security model. But I don't know a lot about it.

Here is something to get you started:

[Discover Techniques for Safely Hosting Untrusted Add-Ins with the .NET Framework 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163701.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If the caller is running on 'Full Trust' there is nothing that can be done. He will always have full access of the assembly.

The best is to obfuscate the assembly. That will make the assembly a bit tougher to re-engineer.

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood me. I am the caller, and I am calling someone else's assembly.