# Prevent changing the value of String.Empty

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Partially from a curious breaking things point of view and partially from a safeguarding  against potential problems. Imagine what is the worst that can happen by calling the following (or something similar, but `string.Empty` is a good examples):

```
typeof(String).GetField("Empty", 
    BindingFlags.Public | 
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
    BindingFlags.Static | 
    BindingFlags.GetField
).SetValue(null, "foo" );
```

This would cause problems when there's code somewhere that does `x = myClass.bar ?? string.Empty`.

Is there any way (akin to different app domains or similar) to protect against (or detect) someone changing values like `String.Empty` or perhaps the `SqlDateTime.MinValue` (or other similar readonly fields in .NET)?

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447939/is-it-possible-to-disable-reflection-from-a-net-assembly

Comment: You can't prevent trusted code from doing bad stuff. And untrusted code can't modify `string.Empty`. And the shooting yourself in the foot is pretty explicit in this case.

Comment: By the way, isn't `Int.MaxValue` a *constant* field?

Comment: String.Empty is *readonly*, not *const*.  That's a very significant optimization at runtime, a direct pointer load and no garbage collection.  Fast and safe are often conflicting goals.  There are not exactly a lot of questions at SO from programmers that accidentally corrupted String.Empty, this is not a real problem.  The SO faq needs to apply here: `practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face`.

Comment: @HansPassant, I guess its not about String.Empty, but such code can lead to security issue, read only means read only, if I set some hash key or things like that assuming no one will modify, I will leave a security hole. I guess .net runtime should maintain reflection consistency at runtime same as that of compile time. And I really do not think that this question does not fit in SO criteria, it is very well a problem.

Comment: @AkashKava How is it a "security" issue? If you're loading and running untrusted code into your process _and_ letting it use reflection APIs then you have a lot more to worry about than `readonly` fields being mutated, besides, [the code is already on the other side of the airtight hatchway](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060508-22/?p=31283).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could define your own `const` fields in *your* assembly like so:

```
internal const string Empty = "";
```

And then perform a check against [`String.Empty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.empty.aspx), but it's pretty much a futile effort.

You'd have to perform a check everywhere you access `String.Empty` and effectively replace it (since you'd check at the point of comparison, there's no point in actually using `String.Empty` over your version anymore).

Since it's `const`, the value couldn't be changed, which is good, but at the same time, if the value of `String.Empty` *does* ever change (however unlikely), you'll have to make the change to your value, and then recompile *everything* that references that field.

Of course, you could make your version `readonly`, but then you'd be vulnerable to having the value changed through reflection, and you're right back where you started.

Add to that the fact that if `String.Empty` was changed, not only would comparisons against the field be affected, but I'd imagine a *tremendous* number of methods in the BCL would just not work properly; looking through Reflector, it would seem it's referenced a few hundred times in mscorlib (.NET 4.0) *alone*:

[image: references to String.Empty in mscorlib 4.0]

So that said, you *could try* and guarantee that the value wasn't changed, but it just isn't practical (it will be an eternal game of cat-and-mouse), chances are, from the perspective of your program, if the value of `String.Empty` was changed, the world would end, and the program would die a horrible death fairly quickly almost as soon as it was changed.